# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka routing expression

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a spring cloud stream application that uses a functional approach. The application uses
a routing expression to filter messages to the consumer function which inspects the payload.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      routing-expression: "payload['type'] == 'Event' ? 'handleEvent' : 'commitIgnoredEvent'"
      definition: functionRouter;handleDlqMessage
```

This configuration gives the exception :

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred
in message handler [org.springframework.cloud.stream.
function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1@3aff91a]; nested exception is 
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
EL1027E: Indexing into type 'org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData$Record'
is not supported, failedMessage=GenericMessage
```

However, this config which uses the header instead will **not**  throw an exception:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    function:
      routing-expression: "header['type'] == 'Event' ? 'handleEvent' : 'commitIgnoredEvent'"
      definition: functionRouter;handleDlqMessage
```

The producing system does not use headers so I cannot use the second option. Does the routing-expression work only with headers? Is there a missing configuration that will enable payload inspection ?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access it as a map. Try `payload.type` (if there is a `getType()` method).

Comment: Thanks Gary that worked!  If you convert the comment to an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access it as a map. Try `payload.type` (assuming there is a `getType()` method).

Comment: The change I made was from  routing-expression: payload['type'] ==                                                                      
 to                                                                                                                                      routing-expression: "payload.get('type') ==