# Spring Cloud Stream Routing to consumer not working

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

Before raising the question: [Spring Cloud Stream Kafka routing expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70008473/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-routing-expression) and [Spring Cloud Function - Separate routing-expression for different Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135632/spring-cloud-function-separate-routing-expression-for-different-consumer)

I am looking to send few orders and based on condition certain consumers only consumed it

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        generateThreeOrderTypes-out-0:
          destination: ordertopic
          content-type: application/json
          
        functionRouter-in-0:
          destination: ordertopic
          content-type: application/json
        
        readOrder-in-0: 
          destination: orderprocessor
          content-type: application/json
      function:
        routing:
          enabled: true

    function:
      definition: generateThreeOrderTypes;readINDOrder;readUSAOrder
      routing-expression: "headers['orderCountry'] == 'IND' ? 'readINDOrder' : 'readUSAOrder'"
      
      
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    username: guest
    password: guest
    port: 5672
```

MainApp.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

import com.example.demo.model.Order;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<Order>>> generateThreeOrderTypes(){
        List<Message<Order>> orders = new ArrayList<>();
        orders.add(MessageBuilder.withPayload(Order.builder()
                .orderId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .userId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .productId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .build())
                .setHeader("orderCountry", "IND")
                .build());  
        
        orders.add(MessageBuilder.withPayload(Order.builder()
                .orderId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .userId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .productId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .build())
                .setHeader("orderCountry", "USA")
                .build());  
        
        
        orders.add(MessageBuilder.withPayload(Order.builder()
                .orderId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .userId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .productId(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(1, 100))
                .build())
                .setHeader("orderCountry", "IND")
                .build());  
        
        
        return () -> Flux.fromIterable(orders);
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Order> readINDOrder(){
        return order -> System.out.println("== Received Order (IND): "+ order + " at "+ Instant.now().toString());
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Consumer<Order> readUSAOrder(){
        return order -> System.out.println("-- Received Order (USA): "+ order + " at "+ Instant.now().toString());
    }
    
}
```